# Move a child out of panel

Tags: vb.net, forms, panel, mdichild, mdiparent

I use the code down below to start a cmd.exe window and move it into panel1 on my form. I added button1 to it and I like to use that button to move the child out of panel1, back "to the desktop". Does anybody know how to do that? I did some Googling and I can find a lot of examples on how to move a child into a panel or how to move it from one panel to another, but not how to move it out of a panel...
Thanks for any help in advance!
Kind regards,
Eric

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Public Class Form1
    Private WithEvents proc As New Process
    Public Const SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED As UInt32 = 3
    Private Declare Function GetParent Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Int32) As Int32
    Private Declare Function DwmGetWindowAttribute Lib "dwmapi" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal dwAttribute As Integer, ByRef pvAttribute As RECT, ByVal cbAttribute As Integer) As Integer
    Private Declare Function SetParent Lib "user32" (ByVal hWndChild As IntPtr, ByVal hWndNewParent As IntPtr) As IntPtr
    Private Declare Function SetWindowPos Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal hWndInsertAfter As IntPtr, ByVal X As Integer, ByVal Y As Integer, ByVal cx As Integer, ByVal cy As Integer, ByVal uFlags As UInteger) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean
    Private Declare Function ShowWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal nCmdShow As Int32) As Boolean
    Public Structure RECT
        Public left, top, right, bottom As Integer
    End Structure
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        proc.EnableRaisingEvents = True
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd"
        proc.Start()
    End Sub
    Private Sub Tmr_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Shown
        proc.WaitForExit(200)
        If SetParent(proc.MainWindowHandle, Panel1.Handle) <> IntPtr.Zero Then
            SetWindowPos(proc.MainWindowHandle, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, Width, Height, 0)
            ShowWindow(proc.MainWindowHandle, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED)
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        'Code to move the child out of panel1
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Just set the parent to the desktop window. You could presumably get that handle by calling `GetParent` in the first place.

Comment: Hi @John,  Thanks for your help. I don't really understand how this handling works. I added the GetParent function with:
`Public Declare Function GetParent Lib "user32" (ByVal ParentWindow As Long) As Long`
But I don't know what to do next...  Thanks again for your help!
Kind regards, Eric

Comment: I haven't tested this for myself but I would assume that you would call `GetParent` first with the window you want to move and that would give you the handle of its original parent, i.e. the desktop window. You would store that handle somewhere and then, when you want to move the window back again, you call `SetParent` and provide that handle.

Comment: Hi @John, as soon as I use GetParent(proc.MainWindowHandle) to store the handle in a variable, I receive aPInvokeStackImbalance error and the rest of my coding no longer works. I'm afraid I'm trying to implement something which is way over my head. Anyway, thanks for trying to help me.

Comment: A stack imbalance is usually a sign that you have used an API declaration that was written for VB6, but how would we know what you've done, given that you haven't shown us? If you change your code and need more help then show us the new code and update the explanation of what happens. Notice that the API declarations you have already shown use `Integer` or `Int32` all over the place? That's because Windows API functions almost universally use 32-bit numbers. If you have a declaration that uses `Long`, that's an indication that you're using code written for VB6, where `Long` is 32-bits.

Comment: Hi @John,  You're right, that's basically because I do not really fully understand how this is all working. I'm scrapping things together from this site and start fiddling until it does what I want, without ever fully understanding how it works.
But you're absolutely right about sharing what I have, so I stripped everything not related and updated the code above with what I have. It now starts cmd.exe and moves it into panel1. What I'm hoping to achieve is that when you click button1, it moves back out of panel1. Again, thank you **very** much for your help and patience!
Kind regards, Eric

Comment: Hi @John, After some testing I discovered that a `SetParent(proc.MainWindowHandle, IntPtr.Zero)` will move an child process back to the desktop.
The only problem I now have is that the proc.MainWindowHandle only seems to work in the MyBase.Shown sub. If I insert a `msgbox(proc.MainWindowHandle)`, I do get the handle number. But if I do the same in the button1.click sub, it returns 0. So the handle  seems to be gone at that point...
Kind regards, Eric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @john for your help, I have been able to get it working now.
Kind regards,
Eric

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Public Class Form1
    Private WithEvents proc As Process
    Public Const SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED As UInt32 = 3
    Private Declare Function GetParent Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function DwmGetWindowAttribute Lib "dwmapi" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal dwAttribute As Integer, ByRef pvAttribute As RECT, ByVal cbAttribute As Integer) As Integer
    Private Declare Function SetParent Lib "user32" (ByVal hWndChild As IntPtr, ByVal hWndNewParent As IntPtr) As IntPtr
    Private Declare Function SetWindowPos Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal hWndInsertAfter As IntPtr, ByVal X As Integer, ByVal Y As Integer, ByVal cx As Integer, ByVal cy As Integer, ByVal uFlags As UInteger) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean
    Private Declare Function ShowWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal nCmdShow As Int32) As Boolean
    Public Structure RECT
        Public left, top, right, bottom As Integer
    End Structure
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        proc.EnableRaisingEvents = True
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd"
        proc.Start()
    End Sub
    Private Sub Tmr_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Shown
        proc.WaitForExit(200)
        If SetParent(proc.MainWindowHandle, Panel1.Handle) <> IntPtr.Zero Then
            SetWindowPos(proc.MainWindowHandle, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, Width, Height, 0)
            ShowWindow(proc.MainWindowHandle, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED)
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        SetParent(proc.MainWindowHandle, IntPtr.Zero)
    End Sub
End Class
```